# using the back button to a fragment FCs it

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment that after clicking an item in the listview, loads a new fragment. If I use the backbutton to go back to the first fragment I get a FC with this error:

```
3-03 19:37:38.193  30258-30258/com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro.Portfolio$1.onItemSelected(Portfolio.java:93)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:892)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.selectionChanged(AdapterView.java:879)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.checkSelectionChanged(AdapterView.java:1043)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.handleDataChanged(AdapterView.java:1022)
            at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:180)
            at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:441)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16088)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1226)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16088)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5061)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16088)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5061)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16088)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5061)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16088)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5061)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16088)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5061)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16088)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:651)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16088)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5061)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16088)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5061)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:302)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16088)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5061)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2277)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16088)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2109)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1219)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1403)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1119)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5849)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:786)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:586)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:546)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:771)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:843)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The code for this fragment is:

```
public class Portfolio extends Fragment implements PortfolioGetAllBeers.OnArticleSelectedListener {

    String beerId = "";
    String userName;
    String userID;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //set layout here
        final View theLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_portfolio, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        getActivity().setTitle("Portfolio");

        //get user information
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        userName = prefs.getString("userName", null);
        userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);

        final Spinner portfolioType = (Spinner) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.portfolioSpinner);
        portfolioType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {


            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

                String portfolioChoice = portfolioType.getSelectedItem().toString();


                Log.d("portfolio", portfolioChoice);

                PortfolioGetAllBeers.OnArticleSelectedListener thisOne;
                thisOne = Portfolio.this;

                if( portfolioChoice.equals("All")){


                    //todo: clear second spinner
                    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.addSpinnerLayout);
                    ll.removeAllViews();

                    //get userID
                    //get user data


                    //construct url
                    String url = "myurl1";


                    //async task goes here


                    PortfolioGetAllBeers task = new PortfolioGetAllBeers(getActivity());
                    task.setOnArticleSelectedListener(Portfolio.this);
                    task.execute(url);

                }

                else if (portfolioChoice.equals("Brewery")){

                    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.addSpinnerLayout);
                    ll.removeAllViews();
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)selectedItemView.getContext().getSystemService(selectedItemView.getContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addspinner_layout, null); // inflate addspinner
                    Spinner sp = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.portfolioSpinner2); //portfolioSpinner2
                    ll.addView(v); // add the view to the linear layout

                    //todo: get breweries and fill spinner
                    //get userID
                    //get user data
                    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(selectedItemView.getContext());
                    String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);

                    //construct url
                    String url = "http://beerportfolio.com/app_getAllYourBreweries.php?u=" + userID;


                    //async task goes here
                    new PortfolioGetAllBreweries(selectedItemView.getContext(), thisOne).execute(url);



                }


                else if (portfolioChoice.equals("Style")){

                    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.addSpinnerLayout);
                    ll.removeAllViews();
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)selectedItemView.getContext().getSystemService(selectedItemView.getContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addspinner_layout, null); // inflate addspinner
                    Spinner sp = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.portfolioSpinner2); //portfolioSpinner2
                    ll.addView(v); // add the view to the linear layout

                    //get userID
                    //get user data
                    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(selectedItemView.getContext());
                    String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);



                    //construct url
                    String url = "myurl2";



                    //todo: async task goes here

                    new PortfolioGetAllStyles(selectedItemView.getContext(), thisOne).execute(url);

                }

                else if (portfolioChoice.equals("Rating")){

                    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.addSpinnerLayout);
                    ll.removeAllViews();
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)selectedItemView.getContext().getSystemService(selectedItemView.getContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addspinner_layout, null); // inflate addspinner
                    Spinner sp = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.portfolioSpinner2); //portfolioSpinner2
                    ll.addView(v); // add the view to the linear layout

                    //get userID
                    //get user data
                    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(selectedItemView.getContext());
                    String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);

                    //make array

                    //make array list for beer
                    final List<String> tasteList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    tasteList.add("1");
                    tasteList.add("2");
                    tasteList.add("3");
                    tasteList.add("4");
                    tasteList.add("5");

                    // Selection of the spinner
                    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.portfolioSpinner2);

                    // Application of the Array to the Spinner
                    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(selectedItemView.getContext(),   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,tasteList );
                    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
                    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);



                    //todo: add on select for spinner 2
//add on item selected
                    final Spinner portfolioType = (Spinner) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.portfolioSpinner2);
                    portfolioType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {


                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

                            String portfolioChoice = portfolioType.getSelectedItem().toString();

                            //Toast.makeText(((Activity) c).getApplicationContext(), portfolioChoice, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            final ListView lv = (ListView) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.allYourBeersList);
                            lv.setAdapter(null);

                            //get brewery beers
                            //get userID
                            //get user data
                            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(selectedItemView.getContext());
                            String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);



                            try {

                                portfolioChoice = URLEncoder.encode(portfolioChoice, "UTF-8");
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            //construct url
                            String url = "myurl3";

                            Log.d("portfolio" , url);
                            //async task goes here
                            PortfolioGetAllBeers task = new PortfolioGetAllBeers(getActivity());
                            task.setOnArticleSelectedListener(Portfolio.this);
                            task.execute(url);



                        }



                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                            // do nothing
                        }

                    });




                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                // do nothing
            }

        });



        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return theLayout;

    }

    @Override
    public void onArticleSelected(String bID, String brewery){

        //code to execute on click
        Fragment Fragment_one;
        FragmentManager man= getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction tran = man.beginTransaction();
        Fragment_one = new BeerPage();
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("beerIDSent", bID);
        bundle.putString("breweryIDSent", brewery);
        Fragment_one.setArguments(bundle);
        tran.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_one);//tran.
        tran.addToBackStack(null);
        tran.commit();

    }

}
```

Line 92 that the error refers to is:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)selectedItemView.getContext().getSystemService(selectedItemView.getContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Comment: there is no "caused by..." later in the stack trace?

Comment: check line 93 of your Portfolio.java "onItemSelected(Portfolio.java:93)"

Comment: what do you mean by caused by?

Comment: @Mike Often an exception causes another (and sometimes causes another again). E.g. an exception is thrown if an activity couldn't be created which was caused by an IOException because the `onCreate()`-Code tried to read a file which didn't exist.

Comment: Try to subdivide the line further and use debugger or logcat to find out, if `selectedItemView` is null, create an own line `Context ctx = selectedItemView.getContext()` and check if `ctx` is null

Comment: is there a way to override something to always make the fragment start fresh when it is loaded from the back button?

Comment: When you press the back button the Fragment manager pop the last added fragment from the back stack(it doesnt recreate the fragment), so you might not save them on the back stack and create the fragment once again. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do not refer to context this way.

Use:

```
Context ctx = getActivity();
```

And then use `ctx` where you use `selectedItemView.getContext()`

Instead of geting LayoutInflater from system service, try:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
```

See if this helps :)